# Removing Protection Around Trader Settlements

Tags: 7-days-to-die

Is there any way to disable protection (which prevents you from building or destroying anything in/around a trader settlement)? Are there any console commands i could use, or some other ways to get around this protection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on a PC you can modify the `prefabs.xml` file. Set `trader_area="False"` and reduce all `protection` values to `0` that should remove the trader protection and disable the teleport feature.

As far as I know there is no claim block in the trader area so building near it after the xml changes are made should be possible.

If you are on a console, you can't change the xml files as far as I know and you won't be able to do that.

If you play on a server, the server admin will have to make the changes to the xml files there.

Comment: Will that also allow the zombies to destroy the trader's outer walls? During the day I like the protection it offers during an ill-equipped wandering horde, because they can't damage the walls, so I stand above and plink them away with a bow, but that could be dangerous if they can now destroy the walls.

Comment: Yes, when protection is removed than the Trader Outpost becomes just like any other building and can be destroyed by zombies. However, currently, still in A18, Trader NPC cannot be killed so you theoretically always will be able to use the trader even if the outpost is gone :) I am not a modder so I can't tell you if it would be possible to only enable protection part of the time. Though if you ask Khaines on twitter (maker of Darkness Falls mod) he could answer that most likely.